# Paste/CTRL-V doesn't work, Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, copy-paste, clipboard

I'm running a Win7 Pro machine with an i5-4430, 8GB RAM, and a Radeon HD 7570. Every once in a while (a few times a day), pasting/ctrl-v does not work.  After leaving it alone for a bit, it will start working again.  Can anyone help me troubleshoot the issue?  This is what I have so far:

- I have tried multiple keyboards, the problem persists across all keyboards.
- I have tried reinstalling windows files (by using the CD and choosing "upgrade")
- I have downloaded clipboard software - I can see that copying works (the clipboard accurate reflects what I just copied), but pasting has no effect.
- I have tried pasting into various software when it comes up, but to no avail (normally I'm pasting into word, excel, or outlook, but I have tried pasting to notepad and paint with no luck).
- There seems to be no pattern to when it strikes.

All out of ideas. Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Are other hotkeys working? (for example, Ctrl+C and Win+M)

Comment: Does Right Click->Paste work?

Comment: Yes - other hotkeys (such as ctrl-c) work.  click-Paste does not work.